# Query multiple servers for counter information - PowerShell, Workflow

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

I'm trying to query multiple Hyper-V hosts for current CPU & RAM (Average of 5 samples) and Disk usage. I want all the queries to be in parallel, the end result being that I want to pick a host with the most resource to create a VM on.

I couldn't get this to work with Get-Counter on its own because each counter will be checked in sequence, I tried using Jobs, but couldn't get nested jobs to work properly. So finally I'm trying with Workflows, the problem that I'm having is that I can't figure out how to store the information in a meaningful way. I tried to use hash tables in a hash table, but that isn't valid in a workflow, what I used was:

```
$HostResources["$Server"] = @{ "CPU"=$CPU; "RAM"=$RAM; "Disk"=$Disk }
```

I also get the feeling that there may be a better way to do this, including enabling Hyper-V metering but that doesn't seem to give information on the host, only on VM's. So if you think there is a better way, point me in the right direction and I'll go an research it.

```
Workflow Get-Resources {

$Servers = @('host00', 'host01', 'host02', 'host03')
# $HostResources = @{}

ForEach -Parallel ($Server in $Servers) {
    InlineScript { (Get-Counter -Counter "\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time" -ComputerName $using:Server -SampleInterval 1 -MaxSamples 5).CounterSamples.CookedValue | Measure-Object -Average | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Average }
    InlineScript { (Get-Counter -Counter "\Memory\Available MBytes" -ComputerName $using:Server -SampleInterval 1 -MaxSamples 5).CounterSamples.CookedValue | Measure-Object -Average | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Average }
    InlineScript { (Get-Counter -Counter "\LogicalDisk(_Total)\% Free Space" -ComputerName $using:Server).CounterSamples.CookedValue }
    }
}

$Result = Get-Resources
```

Comment: Why do you want all of the queries to be in parallel? What advantage is that giving you?

Comment: Currently I'm only checking three counters, I will be considering adding more, network bandwidth, disk iops, queue length, etc. These will add more time per host, on top of which the list of hosts is much higher than shown in the code. I'd like my script to be as quick as possible to keep the deployment time down. If its all in sequence, it could take ten's of minutes to check all the hosts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this implementation using `Start-Job`, you will get your results at the end in `$HostResources` and can easily add further counters to `$counters` or `$countersAV`(for averaged counters):

```powershell
$Servers = @('host00', 'host01', 'host02', 'host03')
    foreach($server in $servers){   
        start-job -Name $server -ScriptBlock {param($server)
            $countersAV = @("\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time","\Memory\Available MBytes")
            $counters = @("\LogicalDisk(_Total)\% Free Space")
            foreach($counterAV in $countersAV){
                echo ($server + $counterAV + ":" + ((Get-Counter -Counter $counterAV -ComputerName $server -SampleInterval 1 -MaxSamples 5).CounterSamples.CookedValue | Measure-Object -Average | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Average))
            }
            foreach($counter in $counters){
                echo ($server + $counter + ":" + ((Get-Counter -Counter $counter -ComputerName $Server).CounterSamples.CookedValue))
            }
        } -ArgumentList $server 
    }   
$HostResources =  (Get-Job | Wait-Job | Receive-Job)
Get-Job | Remove-Job #clean up
```

Result:

```powershell
host00\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time:0.800450654666718
host00\Memory\Available MBytes:5772
host00\LogicalDisk(_Total)\% Free Space:51.8221343719115
host01\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time:0.386754157141649
host01\Memory\Available MBytes:2717
host01\LogicalDisk(_Total)\% Free Space:67.5283240005209
...
```

Comment: You could also use `invoke-command -throttlelimit X -computername $Servers` in place of the outer `foreach` loop to run the scriptblock in parallel on up to `X` servers at a time.